# ASP.NET MVC: When does script bundling decide to change the version of a bundle?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I used to put "?v=n" at the end of my scripts references, like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Foo.js")?v=2"></script>
```

Each time I edited a .js, I added 1 to that versioning, eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Foo.js")?v=3"></script>
```

I decided this couldn't continue being like that (I have too many scripts now), so I started using the ASP.NET MVC bundling feature (`BundleConfig, BundleCollection, RegisterBundles`, et c).

Indeed a version is automatically assigned to the bundle:

```
<script src="/Scripts/Bundles/Foo?v=EjpuCsTAfNN9NMv5E8hER41p25Zj9w6ncqWRsYdqQUY1"></script>
```

**My question is:** 

When does that version change? Can I rely on this? How does it work internally?

I might be wrong but one time I had to manually refresh the browser so that the script was updated, because the **minor change** I did to the script **didn't took effect on the version.**

What could have caused this?
Are minor changes considered in the versioning?

Comment: Version assigned when you run your application! If you are using iis then you have to restart IIS.  If you are using IIS Express stop and start application again version will change automatically.

Comment: Thanks. I've noticed already that though, and that is answering "when" but not "how" :)

Comment: According to my practical experiences I believe that it is far better that you implement or override your own bundling with strict caching mechanisms than using built-in facilities as it's very hard to know how exactly are working and whether they function properly or not, furthermore, inability to track and debug reduce your value added you may want to deliver to your clients through using bundles

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### How does .net generates the version of bundle?

The version of bundle is a **`SHA256 based hash` of all bundled content**.

So if you will change any data of bundled files - version will be changed.

Comment: This doesn't seems to be the case in hosted environment. The bundle version change when the build of the project or web config changes.